# Recording all mouse click and keyboard events in linux [Python]

Tags: python, xlib

I need a function that when will return `true` or `false` depending on whether a mouse event was recorded. Right now I'm using python-Xlib to record cursor positions, but the amount of documentation for the module is really sparse. It seems the only way to get familiar with it is to dig through the source code.

I'm not talking about keeping track of a gui being pressed or anything like that, I need raw input from the mouse.

Comment: Maybe `Pygame` will resolve your problem : https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mouse.html .

Comment: That may be, but I'd like to do this as low-level as possible. I was hoping to use Xlib since it *should* be possible.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [pyHook](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyHook).

It handles tons of events at relatively low-level (Windows Only).

If you need examples, you'll find a lot of projects around the web, such as [this one](https://github.com/ajinabraham/Xenotix-Python-Keylogger/blob/master/xenotix_python_logger.py)

If you are on Linux, there is also [pyxhook](https://github.com/JeffHoogland/pyxhook)